# How do I fix the problem with the incorrect array value in for loop using C language?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, pointers

I am trying to understand how array boundaries work in C, so tried the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
{
   int i, s[4], t[4], u=0;

// fisrt loop

    for (i=0; i<=4; i++)

{
    s[i] =i;
    t[i] =i;

    printf("s = %d\n", s[i]);
    printf("t = %d\n", t[i]);
}

 // second loop

    printf("s:t\n");

    for (i=0; i<=4; i++)

    printf("%d:%d\n", s[i], t[i]);
    printf("u = %d\n", u);

}
 return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows :

```
fisrt loop
s = 0
t = 0
s = 1
t = 1
s = 2
t = 2
s = 3
t = 3
s = 4
t = 4
second loop
s:t
4:0
1:1
2:2
3:3
4:4
u = 0
```

I am expecting both loops to print 5 elements from 0 to 4. As you can see, the first for loop's output looks ok, but in the second loop the value of s[0]
is wrong and for some reason turned to 4.
I am assuming that this is happening because of some problem in the array boundary, but I am not sure, please correct me if I am wrong. Is there any way to fix this, and make s[0] correct value? Cheers.

Comment: You are accessing out-of-the-bound of array in loop: `for (i=0; i<=4; i++)`.

Comment: You are doing out-of-bound access. Array indices range from 0 to N-1 (in this case 0 to 3 both inclusive).

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62951660/4386427

Comment: Your question missing to explain if you want to have the arrays of 5 or 4 `int` elements. The "*the first for loops output looks ok*" isn't sufficient for me to identify that you really want to have 5 elements. - What is your *expected* output?

Answer (score 0):

*If you want to have 5 elements for both arrays:*

Change the declarations of `s` and `t` to `s[5]` and `t[5]`. Only at the declaration the `5` means `5` elements. Only at indexing and addressing a certain element, counting starts at `0`, not `1`.

---

*If you want to have the arrays to be consisted of 4 elements:*

```
for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
```

`i <= 4` - With this condition and the initialization `i = 0` you access memory beyond the bounds of the array at the last iteration, which invokes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/).

When `i == 4`, `s[i]` and `t[i]` is an out of bounds access as `s` and `t` are both arrays of 4 `int`, not 5.

It needs to be `i < 4` or `i <= 3` for the arrays of 4 `int` or (if you want to) or change the initialization to `i = 1`.

Comment: if I do this it returns this s:t  0:0     1:1    2:2     3:3      -13216:0

Comment: @dariahiguchi You need to correct it for both loops.

Comment: @ RobertS supports Monica Cellio , hmmm but then it only counts until 3, so the only way is to decrease the value of i ?

Comment: @dariahiguchi `s[0]` is the first element and `s[3]` is the forth element. When the loop counts up to 4 you attempt to access a non-existing 5th element.

Comment: OP obviously wants 5 elements... From the question "..the first for loops output looks ok.."

Comment: @dariahiguchi Do you want the array to be consisted of 5 elements or 4?

Comment: @4386427 I'm not quite sure about this. This message also could just express that the output in its formally purpose and order is ok. I adjusted my answer for that case. I asked the OP to clarify that.

Comment: The comment from OP just above "... hmmm but then it only counts until 3,..." also clearly shows that OP wants the numbers from 0 to 4 (both included), so the correct answer is: Increase the array size

Answer (score 0):

Delete the equals in the for loops:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
```

The length of the arrays is 4. From 0 to 4 (included) there are 5 positions.

When you declare `int s[4];` you create an arrays of lenght 4: s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3]. You **can't** access s[4].

This is because the position starts to 0.

Answer (score 0):

`for (i=0; i <4; i++)`

in your code you access 5 elements of the array and your array has only 4 elements. It ans Undefined Behaviour.

Second loop the same error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the size of the array, you need to modify your code of that line to given code:

```
int i, s[4], t[4], u=0;
```

to

```
int i, s[5], t[5], u=0;
```

Comment: I wonder why this got a downvote - it's obviously the (first) correct answer. But @ashishkarn you could add a little more description to improve the answer.

Comment: @4386427 Thanks. description can be found on other answers which are also correct.

Comment: We don't know if that is exactly the solution to the problem. OP missed to give more information about that.